# Where is default navigation app (Blue Arrow) in custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-4, navigation

I recently installed the Hyperdrive Android custom ROM version RLS12 on my Samsung S4 and cannot locate the blue arrow icon for navigation.  I do have the Google Maps installed.  Is this something I failed to check off in my install options or is this just gone in RLS12 (I had it in an earlier Hyperdrive release from around October 2013) or is it just hidden and I need a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation has always been a part of the Google Maps application. The icon was essentially a convenience shortcut, but not a separate app, and was removed around [July 2013](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/LtFb26trtiE%5B1-25-false%5D) in the Maps 7.0 update. It's possible you still had the old version of Maps on your other ROM. Either that, or the ROM author added some kind of shortcut "app" to re-create the old Navigation icon or something of that nature.

If you want to use your phone to navigate somewhere, open Google Maps and type the address in the search bar, then hit the button in the bottom right (the exact text/icon may vary depending on distance).

[image]

If you really want the separate Navigation icon, you could possibly downgrade to a version of Maps earlier than 7.0. A custom launcher could also let you create a shortcut directly to the Navigation activity on your desktop, but probably not in the app drawer. Apex Launcher, for example, can create a shortcut on your home screen by long pressing on an empty space on one of your home screens, then selecting `Shortcuts -> Activities -> Maps -> Navigation`.

Comment: Does the new one include voice to text specification of the target address?  What about directions for biking, walking, and public transit?

Comment: @WilliamKF: I'm pretty sure it has all of the same navigation features that it's always had, unless Samsung did something different with it (but I do not think they did). Again, it's literally the same exact app. It previously had **two** icons, one that took you to the main Maps screen and one that took you to directly to the Navigation screen. All they took away (AFAIK) was the second shortcut icon.